# Full width thumbnail on facebook share through my application

Tags: facebook, thumbnails

I have an iOS application and a website for it.
I have set the og properties in my website and used the recommended image size (1200x627) for the og:image.

When I post a link pointing to my website from my facebook account, the thumbnail that is displayed in FB has a full width above the text, but when I post a link through my app pointing to my website the thumbnail is that small, squared one next to the text.

Why is this happening??

Comment: Did you try with a square image instead? If you want the small one next to the text I think the standard size is 200x200

Comment: No no..I want the full width image in both cases! Is that feasible?